# No DNS settings for Parallel Panel 2

Tags: plesk

I don't see DNS settings anywhere, so i searched around and it says to install DNS server /bind. I did but problem still exists. Look at the  pictures:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It´s based on how you enter the Customer Panel.

If you are in the admin-panel and click on domains you´ll see a list of all domains.
If you click on "Manage in Customer Panel" you are logged in with CUSTOMER rights, not ADMIN rights

So: On the domain overview click on the domain name and then you´ll see the DNS options in the Customer Panel, cause now you are "admin" ;)